# what are the risks for disable the abrtd service?

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel, abrt

we have 672 linux redhat machines

since we have small `/var` size
and sometimes `/var/spool` take space , then we want to disable the `abrtd` service

what are the risks for disable the `abrtd` service ?

as the following:

```
systemctl stop abrtd
systemctl stop abrt-oops
```

and

```
systemctl disable abrtd
systemctl disable abrt-oops
```

Comment: abrt is awful. Makes my computer hangs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this Red Hat solution article: [What would be the impact of disabling the ABRT service?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/656643) :

> - What is the impact of disabling the ABRT service ?
>
> The user would not
>   be reported of any crashes happening on the system and would need to
>   monitor the system and `/var/log/messages` constantly for any crashes
>   happening. User should consider disabling the service only if `ABRT`
>   service is of low importance in your environment and have an alternate
>   problem detecting tool monitoring the system.

Further references, including the appropriate stop/disable commands for RHEL 5/6/7 are present in the same solution article.

If you want to study the ABRT service in more detail before making a decision, start with this solution article: [What is Automatic Bug Reporting Tool (ABRT)?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/327173)